# SQL LOADER GIVING ERROR

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I execute the command and get following message at console:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
SQLLDR APPS@VIS/APPS CONTROL=

SQL*Loader: Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Sep 2 10:49:27 2003

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 27
----------------------------------------------------------------------

WHEN I CHECK THE RECORDS I COULD NOT SEE DATA IN THE XXB_RJT_STAGING TABLE 

My control file is as follows:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
LOAD DATA
INFILE ''
INTO TABLE XXB_RJT_STAGING
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(
FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME
)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I created STAGE.CSV File from my EXCEL sheet.

WHEN I CHECKED MY STAGE.BAD FILE ITS SAYS

```
FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME
MIKE,STONE
ROHAN,SPEED
```

Comment: Don't shout - people don't like it.

Comment: What messages have you got in the log file?

Comment: i am not getting any log file. only file after i run sqlldr that i am getting is bad file....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the log,bad and discard options to your command and look what's in it.

```
#>sqlldr userid=username/password control=yourcontrolfile.ctl data=yourdata.csv log=yourlogfile.log bad=yourbadfile.bad  discard=yourdiscardfile.disc
```

I use a controlfile for csv files created from excell like this:

```
options (skip =6)
load data
append
into table table_name
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
(column_name1
,column_name2
,etc.
)
```

Skip = 6 is to skip the headers from the file

Answer (score 0):

Add a log file into the CTL and see what the log file says.
Also, if you post the table definition, it may give a clue (eg it may not have those columns in it).